The yet hidden identity
Can you guess who I am?
My mother is the only person in my life.
My room is small, but perfect for my art.
My biggest wish is to see the stars.
Merely how long will it take?
I wish my mother wasn't that worried about me.
But I may not forget, I'm a special one.
Later, my boyfriend met me, who helped me a lot.
My only weapon is a pan.

Hi Kathi, in case you're wondering about all the downvotes, I think one likely reason is that some people feel they have been cheated: this looks like an interesting riddle, with several opportunities for cunning word play and clever interpretations of the clues, but when combined with the accepted answer from below, it turns out it was all just a quiz question, and not really a riddle at all.

I don't care to be honest, if you don't like it okay, do it better then.

It is

 Rapunzel from the movie Tangled.

